# Is it possible to leave fields as raw text when deserializing?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have json like this

```json
{
    "guid": "b1e3c29f-066f-417b-b6b6-795ffae90f0a",
    "status": "complete",
    "type": "colors",    
    "results": {
        "events": [
            {
                "title": "event1",
                "other": {
                    "Red": "red",
                    "Green": "green",
                    "Blue": "blue"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "event2",
                "other": {
                    "Yelow": "yellow",
                    "Orange": "orange"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and classes for deserialization looks like this

```cs
public class Other
{
    public string Red { get; set; }
    public string Green { get; set; }
    public string Blue { get; set; }
    public string Yelow { get; set; }
    public string Orange { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Other other { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public List<Event> events { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string guid { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Results results { get; set; }
}
```

When I deserialize this json with

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(JsonContent);
```

everything works fine.

The problem is that the content of json section `"Other"` is changeable and I don't know its complete content.
Also I need to put this classes in database.

Is there a way to deserialize json section `"Other"` as one string field with raw text, and to look something like this:

```cs
public class Other
{
    public string AllFieldsFromOtherSectionAsRawText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Newtonsoft Json.NET, right?

Comment: You could change the type of `Other` to `JObject`, at which point it's just "some arbitrary JSON object"

Comment: Yes, Newtonsoft Json.NET.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, you saved my day! :) Your idea is best for my scenario! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your `Other` class like this:

```
public class Other
{
    public Other(string rawData)
    {
        Content = rawData;
    }
    public string Content { get; }
}
```

Then you can write a custom `JsonConverter`, which will treat your `other` nodes as `string`:

```
class ObjectToStringJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type theType;
    public ObjectToStringJsonConverter(Type type) => theType = type;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == theType;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(theType, args: token.ToString()); 
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException("The related node is not object");
    }
}
```

The only trick here is this line:

- `Activator.CreateInstance(theType, args: token.ToString());`
- Here we create a new `Other` instance and pass the string representation of the `other` node to the constructor.

Then the usage would look like this:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json, new[] { new ObjectToStringJsonConverter(typeof(Other)) });
```

Answer (score 1):

Isnt Other a Dictionary represenation?

Can't you write it as Dictionary

```
public Dictionary<String,String> other { get; set; }
```

Example:

```
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
    public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string> other
```

According to the documentation, you DeserializeObject on type Dictionary:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm

Comment: It was my idea too, but I don't know how to set up Newtnsoft.Json deserializer to write it in the dictionary.

Comment: JsonExtensionData is for adding undefined fields to an object, if json has fields A,B,C,D but your defined object has properties A,B only then C and D are ignored unless you have an JsonExtensionData flagged dictionary in which case they are added to that in this case other is a defined item in the json so can just be deserialised directly to the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Remove class Other from your code, and fix Event class

```
public class Event
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "other")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> otherDict { get; set; }
    
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<string> Other
    {
        get { return  otherDict.Values.ToArray(); }
    }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
    public string AllFieldsFromOtherSectionAsRawText
    {
        get { return string.Join(",", Other);  }
    }
}
```

output

```
{
  "guid": "b1e3c29f-066f-417b-b6b6-795ffae90f0a",
  "status": "complete",
  "type": "colors",
  "results": {
    "events": [
      {
        "title": "event1",
        "other": {
          "Red": "red",
          "Green": "green",
          "Blue": "blue"
        },
        "AllFieldsFromOtherSectionAsRawText": "red,green,blue"
      },
      {
        "title": "event2",
        "other": {
          "Yelow": "yellow",
          "Orange": "orange"
        },
        "AllFieldsFromOtherSectionAsRawText": "yellow,orange"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```